# Knowing why a form is not valid in Django

Tags: django, django-forms

I am doing an inline formset which appear not to be valid. I don't see a way to get from Django an explicit sentence explaining what causes the form not be valid. Does that exist ? Like an help for te programmer ?

```
def change_uploaded_infos(request):
if request.method=='POST':
    FielsdFormSet = inlineformset_factory(User, field)
    formset=FielsdFormSet(request.POST)
    if formset.is_valid() :
        return HttpResponse("ok")

return render(request, "change_uploaded_infos.html", {
    "formset": formset,
})
```

I would like to be able to do "if not valid => return an exception text message given by Django".

Comment: If this is your exact code, you should already be getting the formset invalid message. Note that I would move the initialization of the formset above the factory.

Comment: How can I get the formset invalid message ? Is it given back by is_valid () ? (I didn't try that)

Comment: use`formset.errors` to get form errors.

Comment: excellent ! Know I got : "The inline foreign key did not match the parent instance primary key", much better, even if I don't have a clue :)

Comment: @user3318273 I posted it in an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just  use `formset.errors`

```
if request.method=='POST':
    FielsdFormSet = inlineformset_factory(User, field)
    formset=FielsdFormSet(request.POST)
    if formset.is_valid() :
        return HttpResponse("ok")
    else:
        errors = formset.errors

return render(request, "change_uploaded_infos.html", {
    "formset": formset,
})
```